# php allow access to admin dismiss to user

Tags: php, admin

I have a db with a column called "status" and another called "username".
If the value in the column "status" equals to 1, the user is admin, if the value is 2 and will get a message in echo, is he isn't he will get nothing. In the column username, there all the username stored...

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser where username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  if($row['status'] == 1)
{
   echo "you are admin!";
}
```

I don't know what I am doing false... If you could help me out, would be nice

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Do you have any `session_start()` somewhere, before you trying to access the `$_SESSION`-variable? If not, you need to.

Comment: 1. Check your config.php file. The very first line has to be session_start(); if it is not. 2. As Magnus Eriksson has mentioned above, change your connection using mysqli and use mysqli for your database related queries.

Comment: First check what are you getting in $username by just echoing before constructing your sql query. Then check what your are storing in $sql before sending to mysql to fetch records.